# What is the use of users awarding bounties to themselves on different accounts?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have given an answer to a bounty [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869066/android-song-picturealbum-art-is-not-coming-in-music-player-app/34990511) asked by user [@shivam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5408662/shivam)

Now, this user said he will try this answer by using his other account. (I know that because the comment *"ok, I will try."* came from another [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3196995/shivam)).

Now what he did is that he copied my answer and posted it using the other account and also accepted that answer. Now, he got the bounty and the accepted answer.

I have personally checked that question and gave my time to give an answer but to no use.

I'm raising this question, not because I didn't get bounty, but because this type of scenario must be handled. A developer gives their precious time to give an answer and then just feels cheated.

Comment: Looks like they posted two answers, one with each account. Flag the question for moderator attention and explain what is going on (you can also provide a link to this meta-question). They know how to deal with this kind of abuse.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?  Looks like the accounts were merged and the user has been suspended for a week.

Comment: I appreciate every answer that is given on Stackoverflow and am always so thankful for our community.   Knowledge can be hard to come by sometimes.  Nobody should ever try to get someone else's credit - ever!  It's such a disgrace!  It's not a popularity contest..

Comment: Yes you are right @SDJ

Comment: @KDeogharkar Looks like you just got a reversal! Much more worth while than a small bounty

Comment: Yes I never expect that much but I put a valid question right mate.

Comment: Kind of OT: Answering off-topic question is disregarded as well.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

> What is the use of users awarding bounties to themselves on different accounts?

To cheat the system, because [a bounty cannot normally be re-awarded to the same user who offered it in the first place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work); awarding a bounty to a self-answer results in no reputation being awarded. The only time a bounty can be legitimately refunded is when a moderator does so in exceptional cases — and only when the bounty *hasn't* yet been awarded.

This particular user wasn't even being sneaky about it. They just straight up decided you'd answered their question for them and used another account to grab the bounty knowing bounties cannot be self-awarded. It was utterly *not cool* of them to dupe you into answering their bountied question only to do this.

I'm sorry this has happened to you. Unfortunately we cannot transfer bounties across answers once awarded, but if it's any consolation the other account has been deleted completely, along with the bounty — which means when they return from their suspension they'll find that they've lost 50 of their reputation for good.

Here's a tip for askers: if you can't bear to let go of your reputation for the sake of finding answers, don't post a bounty. No one's making you. There are other legitimate ways to bring attention to your question that don't cost you reputation, such as editing.

Comment: Its really okay@BoltClock that I dont get bounty and thanks for your quick action . Users should learn lesson from this event that it is not easy to cheat SO and also not good thing to.. happy coding :)

Comment: How do you decide that which account should be deleted? . Is it based on bounty or is there any other criteria ?

Comment: We keep whichever looks like it's the "main" account. For example if one account is older, or has lots of rep, compared to the others, then we delete the rest. Or if a user is question-banned and they're using alt accounts to evade the ban, we delete the ban evasion accounts.

Comment: \[[meta-tag:feature-request]\]: always leave the *lowest*-rep sock puppet account alive, and delete the rest:) That could be inspirational.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think that will be too harsh at first time . User will take this action as a warning so he/she never do this kind of mistake again and also get a change to do it right .

Comment: @Andras Deak: That would free users from their question bans if their socks weren't also banned.

Comment: BoltClock I'm sure those bans could be migrated as well;) OK, I know those are ingrained in the software, and I wasn't *entirely* serious in the first place. @KDeogharkar I'd think that blatant offenders like yours are likely to retry in a more subtle way (but I have zero experimental evidence to back this up, just a guess based on human nature).

Comment: Is this status-completed yet?

Comment: what about the Altruist and Investor badges, both apparently received for the bounty in question?

Comment: @kostja: They'll keep the badges. And with them, the knowledge that what they did was anything but an act of altruism.

Comment: The meta effect probably compensated OP for the stolen bounty :)

Comment: The remaining account has/will benefit from two accepts from the deleted account.

Comment: @KDeogharkar - This isn't hacking off a hand for stealing an apple, it is removing unicorn points (which they can earn back) for blatantly and intentionally deceiving other users and belittling the amount of time and effort they have spent in trying to help someone in need they don't know for no real gain to themselves. If you ask me there isn't a worse thing you can do on SO.